# Finite set of vectors approximating a unit ball.

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, geometric-probability

I am having difficulty proving that a unit ball can be approximated with a set of finite vectors. Specifically, I want to bound the error of the following approximation.

Let $D$ be a uniform distribution over an $d$-dimensional unit ball and $D'$ be a the uniform distribution over $\{-1,0,1\}^d$. Then show that, for any vector $a$ sampled from $D$, with high probability there exists a non-empty set of vectors 
$$
V = \left\{v \left|
                \frac{v\cdot a}{\|v\|\ \|a\|} \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{d}}\right.
    \right\}
$$ sampled from $D'$. Moreover, for $A = \sum_{v \in V} v$, show that $\frac{A\cdot a}{\|A\|\|a\|}$ is close to 1.

In high dimensions, any two vectors picked at random are orthogonal with high probability. So, even though each vector in $V$ has dot product at least $\frac{\|v\|\|a\|}{\sqrt{d}}$ with $a$, their average might be closer to $a$. I want to bound this error. Pointers to any existing results in the high dimensional probability for such approximations would be helpful too.

Comment: This sounds like an assigned exercise.  If you can explain your interest in the problem with your Readers, it may improve the Question in several ways.  For example, you might be reading a paper in which the author makes a claim similar to the above, and you would like to make it more precise or see a discussion of methods of proof.  In any case bare problem statements (lacking such context) are often put on hold awaiting editing.

Comment: @hardmath thanks for the comment. I have edited the question now. Its not an exercise question. I am stuck at bounding this approximation error to use in my work.

Comment: Once you take $a/||a||$, you have essentially sampled uniformly from the $d-1$ dimensional *unit sphere* (rather than from $D$).  Likewise the vectors $v/||v||$ will (if the exceptional vector $v=0$ is omitted) be the projections onto the unit sphere.  Asking how often the dot product of those projections exceeds $1/\sqrt d$ is really about the (cosine of the) angle between $a$ and the discrete vectors $v$.

Comment: @hardmath, yes. Its cosine of the angle. What would be cosine of the angle between average of vectors in $V$ and $a$ is what I am stuck at.

Comment: It seems like a tractable problem!  Let me think on this.

Comment: Some related ideas are found in [this MathOverflow Question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/167793/bound-on-maximum-distance-between-points-on-a-unit-n-sphere), "Bound on maximum distance between points on a unit $n$-sphere".